# stop ng-repeat when match ng-if

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an object person like this:

```
person:
    phone:
      phone1:
        number:"xxx-xxx-xxxx"
        checkedSms:true/false
      phone2:
        number:"xxx-xxx-xxxx"
        checkedSms:true/false
    smsNumber:""
```

I have a link `<a>` I only want to display it under certain condition: either one of the phones `checkedSms` is true(`person.phone.phone[i].checkedSms = true`) or `smsNumber.length > 0`.

I can do the second part by this:

```
    <a ng-click="..." ng-if="person.smsNumber.length > 0"
        <div>
             ...
        </div>
    </a>
```

But I don't know how to add the first part, and combine it with the second part above. Tried `ng-repeat` to repeatly checking on phones of person, but multiple matching results in multiple `<a>` display. The link should only show once, whenever one condition matches, it should stop further checking.

Hope somebody can help me out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the phone property an array or just an object with phone1 and phone2 properties?

Comment: Why not use a method that filters the data on the controller side (whatever it is that you are checking) and returns the filtered array?

Comment: Avoid adding business logic into your html, because you will not be able to unit test it, better to add the business logic in the controller and have the result in a property of your scope or viewmodel and this is what you need to bind to in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

In the HTML:

```
<a ng-if="checkForSms()" ng-click="...">
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.checkForSms = function() {
// code that returns true if the conditions are met
}
```

Also, I would start using "controllerAs" syntax to prepare for Angular 2.0. https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/preparing-for-the-future-of-angularjs#3-2-remove-dependencies-on-scope

Answer (score 1):

I would create a property in the controller, call it `filterPersonList`

```
$scope.filterPersonList = $scope.personList.filter(function (e) {
   return e.smsNumber.length > 0 || whatever other condition
})
```

Then use ng-repeat with the filterPersonList